# Float change issue on chrome with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change label `{float:left}` to `{float:right}` in *IE* and *Firefox*, it is changing perfectly, but in *Chrome* the floating was not working.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.right_label', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
    $('.labels').css('float', 'right');
  } else $('.labels').css('float', 'left');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="labels">first name</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<select>
  <option class="left_label">left</option>
  <option class="right_label">right</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() {
  $('.labels').css('float', $(this,"option:selected").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="labels">first name</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option class="left_label" value="left">left</option>
  <option class="right_label" value="right">right</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

$(document).on('click','.myselectbox',function(){ } }); , this should not be there, it will only work when you cilck on the element,

while giving a select box we should use

```
$(document).on('change','.myselectbox',function(){ } });
```

check this , and let me know if you dont understand anywhere.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
        <div id="rightleftDiv">
            <label class="labels">first name</label>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>

        <select class="myselectbox" name="myselectbox">
            <option class="left_label" value="left">left</option>
            <option class="right_label" value="right">right</option>
        </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('change','.myselectbox',function(){

            if($(this).val() == 'right'){
                $('.labels').css('float','right');
            }else $('.labels').css('float','left');
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For selectbox i would suggest you to never use on click event. Always use change event.